# Convert string to JSON and save as .json file in php

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a JSON Object. I converted it to string to send data to another page.
I again want to convert that data to JSON and store in a JSON file.

**dwv.min.js:**

```
this.onStateSave=function(){
var e=new H.State;
var new_json = e.toJSON(o);
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(new_json);
jQuery.post("add_annotation_script.php",
            {myJSON:myJSON}
            );
}
```

**add_annotation_script:**

```
$myJSON = (String)$_POST['myJSON'];
$rad = $_SESSION['rad_id'];
$image = $_SESSION['image'];
$case_id = $_SESSION['case_id'];
$jObj = json_decode($myJSON);
$path = "C:/wamp64/www/MIC/anno/".$case_id."/".$image.$case_id.".json";
$f = (file_exists($path))? fopen($path, "a+") : fopen($path, "w+");
fwrite($f, $jObj);
fclose($f);
```

Is this correct or I am missing anything out?

**Errors:**
Undefined index: myJSON

Comment: JSON is a string-based serialization format, just write it directly to file without decoding it.

Comment: @Sammitch I need to store this .json file in server and later extract them and view upon a image(these are the annotations of the image). If I write it directly without decoding then will it work later while loading on the image?